# How can I use the Typography.NumeralAlignment Property on a WP7 textblock?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, typography

I have a text block that should display numbers in this format

[image: Typography:Numeral Alignment:Tabular]

This is supposed to be accomplished via [Typography.NumeralAlignment property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.typography.numeralalignment.aspx) set to "Tabular" but how do I apply this to a Textblock in a Windows Phone 7 application.

Answer (score 1):

This is only supported in SL5 and WP7.1 is based on SL4. I don't know of alternatives, sorry.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.typography.numeralalignment(v=vs.95).aspx

To get this to work in SL4, you will need to essentially implement it yourself..

Comment: oh. Well thanks. Any suggestions on how to implement this kind of kerning. I don't wish to use multiple textblocks for displaying just one number.

Comment: Not really. Your best bet is to look around to see if someone implemented it for SL4 and see if you can adapt it (should be fairly easy at that stage). I looked around a bit, but couldn't find anything promising.